# SVG-изображение с градиентом

Tags: android, svg

Я создала SVG-изображение в Inkscape и пыталась импортировать его в Android-проект. Для рендеринга SVG-изображений я использовала библиотеку [svg-android.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsvgandroidjar.htm), и вот как выглядел код для отображения SVG-изображения в ImageView:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.counter);
Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.counter_image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Но изображения вообще не было видно. После добавления строки:

```
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

изображение стало видимо, но все прямоугольники, в заливке которых был градиент, при запуске приложения оказались залиты чёрным цветом. Вот логи:

> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: sodipodi:namedview
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: inkscape:grid
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: metadata
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: rdf:RDF
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: cc:Work
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: dc:format
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: dc:type
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: dc:title
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ Didn't find shader, using black: linearGradient4279
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ Didn't find shader, using black: linearGradient4295
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ Didn't find shader, using black: linearGradient4315
>
> SVGAndroid﹕ Didn't find shader, using black: linearGradient4315-8

Подскажите, как правильно рендерить SVG с градиентом для Android?

Comment: а вы хотите вектор в итоге получить, или просто картинку из inskape ? Если второе просто конвертируйте svg->png, тогда градиент будет виден.

Comment: хочу получить векторную картинку

Comment: Тогд не получится, сейчас отвечу. Скиньте картинку если можно я посмотрю сложность, есть вариант но он костыльный

Comment: очень много рисовать, вариант имитировать заливкой градиент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fill(s) or stroke(s) which uses url() (gradients and patterns are not
>   supported in Android)

После конвертации градиент выглядит примерно так(в лучшем случае):

```
fillColor="url(#SVGID_1_)"
```

для Android(точней для VectorDrawable) этого ничего не значит, и всё что он может залить(fill) полностью градиент, поэтому пока никак. Последняя новость от 24.02.16 они добавили support lib VectorDrawable

Comment: В моём случае в svg-файле ссылки на градиент выглядят так:
`<rect style="fill:url(#linearGradient4279); ... />`. Но я же не использую VectorDrawable, для конвертации я использую [svg-android.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsvgandroidjar.htm)

Comment: а нужно , иначе это просто Drawable, а вам нужен вектор. 
Для того чтоб решить вашу проблему, можете для градиента использовать GradientDrawable проблемы нет, но это будет не то что вы хотите. Поймите вы используя библиотеку не видите процесс конвертации я вам описал пример в ответе и действительно пока это сложность.